# How to check oracle database network status

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Can anyone please tell me method for checking oracle data base network status?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to check if an Oracle DB is reachable from a Client(network status). Check http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsping

Comment: @Cybernate: Thanks a ton.Yes i meant the same, but i cannot understand from your provided link

Comment: What part didn't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cybernate response is fairly easy from a command prompt:

For DB that is running

```
C:\Users\user_name\tnsping db_name_thats_running
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 17-JUN-2011 10:17:25

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\ora11\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ######)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = db_name_thats_running)))
OK (80 msec)
```

For db that is not running

```
C:\Users\user_name\tnsping db_name_thats_not_running

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 17-JUN-2011 10:17:15

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oracle\ora11\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=fe80::b1d0:b145:b4a0:9b76%11)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=####)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

Alternatively you could just use sql*plus or any other program to try to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to host in which  Listener and Database are running you can check listener status with **tnslsnr** command..

You can see an example of this: [check listener and general database status](http://bbdd-error.blogspot.com.es/2017/09/check-general-database-status.html)